# How to access child records of Extended Collection in Powerdesigner?

Tags: vba, collections, powerdesigner

Help me please!

I created:

- AbstractDataType_1
- AbstractDataType_2
- Table_1
- extended collection for tables in Local Extension (Profile\Table\Extended Collections\Collection_1) of Target Type =  "AbstractDataType"

And I linked Collection_1 to Table_1.

And added to  this relation AbstractDataType_1 and AbstractDataType_2.

How I can read AbstractDataType_1.code in VB-script?

What should be instead of "??????" below?

Should be something instead of "[??????.]"?

```
Dim object, coll
Set object = ActiveModel.FindChildByName("Table_1",cls_Table)
Set coll = object.GetExtendedCollection("Collection_1")
for each coll_member in coll.??????
    output coll_member.[??????.]Code
next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close.

```
option explicit
Dim object, coll, coll_member
Set object = ActiveModel.FindChildByName("Table_1",cls_Table)
Set coll = object.GetExtendedCollection("Collection_1")
for each coll_member in coll
    output coll_member.Code
next

VB Script started on 5/10/2021 at 3:18:03 PM
TYPE_1
TYPE_2
VB Script terminated on 5/10/2021 at 3:18:03 PM.
```